# results show well in the class file, but show strange characters when I include it in the main system?

Tags: php, oop, character-encoding, character

I am currently building a blog system, and the class file i.e class Blog{}, is running ok, when I try it on its own, but, when I try to use it in the pages of the site that have css, it looks weird and full stop, and apostrophes are replaced by strange characters! please help, this is my first time of using oo for development,

Comment: Are you sure, that both the class file and the master file have the same character encoding?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely one of your files have Unicode encoding, Try to open each file with notepad or other text editor and save the file with ANSI encoding.

I had same issue in the past and that was the answer.

Look our for inclusions because they affect the whole process.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem exactly :)